# How to prevent a cell from being highlighted when selected?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have the first column of my AbstractTableModel designated to have a checkbox. But when I click on the checkbox the whole row gets selected. I don't mind this, but I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the first column from being highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) examines the `isSelected` parameter passed to the `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method and sets the selection color accordingly. To affect *all* conforming renderers, You can make the selection color equal to the background color using the relevant `UIManager` keys, `Table.background` and `Table.selectionBackground`.

```
UIManager.put("Table.selectionBackground", UIManager.get("Table.background"));
```

In a acustom renderer, you can specify the same color irrespective of `isSelected`.